# How to display latest values after sync remote db's?

Tags: .net, time, synchronization

There are multiple remote ( not local & not same domain ) db's ( ssce ) where each user can

```
*  look at the current row with the latest updates
*  look at the history of changes made to a row
*  look at the username who made the change
*  look at the time the change was made
```

The problem is there is no way to sync the windows time on these two machines! I am sure this is a common enough issue but nothing that that has come up in my search

any help is appreciated

p/s the machines are online sporadically so cannot rely on a server to get the server time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a solution for those who may visit here looking for answers

on the sender

```
* use a sntp client to get the network time at the time of sync start
* send this n/w time along with the local time with the changes
```

on the recv end

```
* at the time of sync recv, get the n/w time using sntp
* using the above time and the timestamps recvd, map the source timestamps to the local timestamp to figure out the latest changes
```

hope this is of help to someone

Answer (score 0):

What about the server? Why not do save based on the server time not the computer time. This way the time is going to be the same.

Comment: there is no server as of now, one could be introduced but even so they would connect occasionally/ the connection is not guaranteed to be available